# "Why can I not carry this?" or "Why cannot I carry this?" - which is the correct phrasing?

Tags: negation

I'm playing a game and it doesn't let me pick up an item. At some point I asked "Why cannot I carry this?"
My friends are telling me my question is grammatically incorrect. I feel like it might be strange cause I did not use a contraction "can't" but still correct as "cannot" is itself a contraction so the movement of "not" is not necessary. 
What's the story here, please? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it incorrect to say, "Why cannot....?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50251/is-it-incorrect-to-say-why-cannot)

Comment: It's not _grammatically incorrect_, just _not idiomatic_.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, can't is a contraction of cannot - as in 'unable', but "Why cannot I...", whilst grammatically correct, is a very formal way of phrasing the question.  I doubt that it has been in common usage since the 1850's.  To modern ears, it sounds 'odd' or strange.

"Why can't I pick that up?" is an appropriate question, either in a computer game or in general day-to-day interactions.

Comment: _Cannot_ is rarely used in English. It occurs, like most archaic language, principally in writing, where it represents ways in which English used to be spoken.

Comment: Not sure I agree...  It's use does tend to be at the more formal end of the common usage, not so much in TOWIE.  I am Romford born & bred!

Comment: It's rarely used in questions, but not uncommon in statements.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding typical question structures in English will help bring clarity to this question.  Consider, as an example, the tag questions.

- I may eat breakfast in my room, may I not? (more formal)
- I may eat breakfast in my room, mayn't I? (less formal)
- You can swim, can you not? (more formal)
- You can swim, can't you? (less formal)
- I am going with you, am I not? (more formal)
- I'm going with you, aren't I? (less formal)

Notice that in all of these tag questions, the "not", unless contracted, comes last in the sentence.  If contracted, the pronoun comes last.  To phrase the tag as "may not I?" would be incorrect.

While "cannot" is a single word, it is not equivalent to a contraction.  It would be equivalent to one of the other modal verbs combined with the adverb "not" in how it gets used in these questions.

Following this same pattern, the correct phrasing of the OP's question would be:

- "Why can I not carry . . . ?"
  OR
- "Why can't I carry . . . ?"